# Setup 2 VLANs with 2 subnets?

Tags: networking, subnet, vlan

I have one modem - Cisco DPC3010, 2 routers - Netgear WGR614v7 and Linksys BEFSR41v2, and a managed switch - TP-Link TL-SG108E.

Everything seems to be setup correctly for the 2 subnets but I can't figure out what to do with the managed switch so that I can put them in their own VLANs.

Here's the current hardware setup:
Modem (Cisco) connected to router 1's (Netgear) WAN port. Computer 1 connected to router 1's LAN port. Router 1's LAN port connected to router 2's (Linksys) WAN port. Computer 2 connected to router 2's LAN port.

Here's the diagram of a working hardware setup without VLAN's:

[image: Network with 2 routers and 2 subnets.]

Where do I put the smart switch? Between the modem and router 1? Should I connect both routers to the managed switch (for example router 1 on switch port 1 set to VLAN 1, router 2 on port 2 set to VLAN 2, and dedicate first half of the remaining 6 ports to VLAN 1 and the other to VLAN 2?

**Edit1:**
As requested, here's a diagram of the desired setup (but without indication of where to put the managed switch because I don't know where to put it.)
[image: Network with 2 subnets and 2 VLANs]

Comment: What are trying to accomplish? You have two networks, 192.168.0.0/25 and 192.168.0.128/25, you do not have "VLANs" in this scenario.

Comment: I understand that I have subnets and no VLAN's. That's exactly the problem. I just put the diagram in to show the current setup.The desired setup is to put those subnets on VLAN's. I'm trying to setup an isolated VLAN for a DMZ. I understand I'll need a good firewall or 2 to accomplish the end result but I'm just taking this 1 step at a time. If I can setup VLAN's, I'll be able to move on to firewall configurations.

Comment: I still don't know what you are trying to accomplish... So are you saying you want 2 distinctly separate broadcast domains, because that is what you have now. What is not working in the current scenario that you think you need VLANs? Are your routers stock or running a WRT firmware? Are you trying to get the devices on the two subnets to talk to each other? Can your cable modem provide 2 public IPs?

Comment: Everything works, I've just read online that putting VLANs on their own subnet can be more secure than simply using subnets alone. My routers are stock. I do eventually want communication between broadcast domains (or across subnets) but only conditionally. For example, when I put my DMZ on the network, I'll want to 1) restrict inbound internet traffic only to the servers inside the DMZ, 2) allow all outbound traffic from the private network, and 3) allow DMZ traffic to the internet but not my private network. I'm only paying for 1 public IP and don't know how many the modem can handle.

Comment: A diagram on that would help you more.  I still don't understand how you'd need to make your setup even more complex though.  You probably have everything you need to do what you want without adding another device.

Comment: Indeed, a single VLAN capable router can accomplish this far easier. This should look like Cable Modem -> Router w/2 or 3 VLANs -> Switch (tagged for all VLANs) then assign ports as untagged for VLAN 1, 2, or DMZ, and plug hosts into the corresponding ports. If I understand your desired setup correctly, but an end result diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe I don't even need VLANs. I guess maybe I don't understand the purpose of usin VLANs when subnets separate broadcast domains. Isn't that what VLANs do also, split up broadcast domains? If they do the same thing, why implement one over the other?

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious The thing is, home routers like you have are not intended to connect to anything but one external IP (Internet) and one LAN.... A few static router assignments can get some inter-network connectivity between them, but in general this is beyond their capability. Using a WRT firmware on a single router can get mostly the desired results though.

Comment: Ok I'll try to find a compatible router. Do you think 1 WAN port and 4 LAN will suffice?

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious Yes...  I will try to do a simple network diagram after work and post as an answer. I believe one of your routers is DD-WRT/OpenWRT compatible and will work with your basic managed switch to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make a network diagram, but failed miserably... Sorry

Basically what you want to do is either get a commercial grade, VLAN capable router, or get a router capable of running [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) firmware, which neither of your routers are capable of according to either website's hardware database.

From this point there are multiple ways to configure this, but here is a a few general rules I use... Leave the router's default IP address as the "admin VLAN", you won't be accessing it from anywhere but when physically connected to port 1-3 of the router (I will explain port 4 later), leaving this as by default 192.168.1.0/24 and the router being 192.168.1.1 so it can be accessed for maintenance purposes.

Then build the subnets/VLANs, the router will hold an IP address in EACH subnet, so it will have multiple IP address and DHCP scopes. In this example we will use VLAN 10 for your "DMZ" zone (not a real [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) if you will have regular hosts, but it will work for this purpose) and VLAN 20 for your Private LAN.

In the router you will build VLAN 10 and assign IP address of 192.168.10.1/24 to the router and build the DHCP scope accordingly, then do the same with VLAN 20 using 192.168.20.1/24 and another DHCP scope for that network.

In the VLAN assignments, go to Ethernet port 4 and add VLAN 10 and 20 as tagged VLANs... this will be the "downlink" to the switch.

In your managed switch, setup port 1 as untagged into VLAN 1 (you can skip this portion if security is a real concern, it would become an issue if there was a switch misconfiguration or it lost it's configuration), and allow tagged traffic on VLAN 10 and 20. Now map the ports as necessary as untagged into the necessary VLAN, so the port your MS Server is connected to will be untagged into VLAN 10, most of users will be connected to a switch port that is set as untagged into VLAN 20.

In this scenario the router controls everything VLAN/subnet configuration related including inter-VLAN routing and port forwarding ("DMZ" assignments), and the switch basically handles the subnet assignments to individual hosts.

So in a "text" picture this would look like:

WAN side: ISP -> Cable Modem -> Router

Transport side: Router port 4 (trunked with VLAN 1, 10, and 20) -> Switch Port 1

Switch side: Port X is assigned untagged VLAN based on network needed

Then later, if you need to expand, you either setup another port on the router like port 4 and feed another another switch, or build another trunk port on the switch with the VLANs tagged and downlink to a similar port on the new switch.

In no case is there a need for 2 routers in this scenario. You can adjust the IP addresses and subnet masks as needed, the ones I used are just for reference.

Comment: That sounds like a great way to handle it, and I'll definitely use these instructions when I get a dd-wrt/openwrt compatible router. But all I had to do was plug both routers into the managed switch. I plugged in the Netgear to port 1 and the Linksys to port 2. Then I configured the managed switch ports 1,3,4,5 to VLAN1 and 2,6,7,8 to VLAN2. If you post an answer that says "Plug both of your routers into the switch," or something like that, I'll mark it as the solution so you get credit.